# Why my Socket.accept() accept two or three requests?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, httpserver

The Main class:

```
Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final HTTPServer server = new HTTPServer(9999);
        server.start();

        System.out.println("Server started!");

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            server.stop();
            System.out.println("Server stopped!");
        }));
    }
}

HTTPServer {

    // for debug
    private static int threadNumber;
    private final int port;
    private Thread listenThread;

    public HTTPServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    void start() {
        listenThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {

                    while (!interrupted()) {
                        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        threadNumber++;

                        System.out.println(threadNumber+"==========================");
                        socket.getOutputStream().write(("\"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\r\\n\"Connection: close\r\n\r\n").getBytes());
    //                  socket.getOutputStream().write("abrakadabra".getBytes());

                        socket.close();

                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        listenThread.start();
    }

    void stop() {
        listenThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

The above code after one client request prints:

> Server started!
>
> 1==========================
>
> 2==========================

When i replace `socket.getOutputStream().write(("\"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\r\\n\"Connection: close\r\n\r\n").getBytes());` with `socket.getOutputStream().write("abrakadabra".getBytes());`, programm prints:

> Server started!
>
> 1==========================
>
> 2==========================
>
> 3==========================

Comment: please show your client code. it seems that the client simply stops opening sockets after receiving a specific string (in your case, `\"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\r\\n\"Connection: close\r\n\r\n`)

Comment: I send a request from the browser

Comment: what do you exactly do? print IP:port in the address bar of the browser and press Enter once?

Comment: Probably your browser is sending other requests, like favicons etc.?

Comment: @mangusta yes, localhost:9999 and enter once

Comment: @ace, i disabled favicon

Comment: Sometimes browsers (e.g. Chrome) would also try to resend requests if the first one failed. Would that be the case? Try using `wget` or `curl` instead of a browser, and see if it makes any difference.